# User-level command shell change for accessing remote machine with paramiko

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, tcsh

I use some code connecting with remote machine with use of paramiko library. The connection is established over tunnelling `ssh` connection bound to one of the localhost ports. The default shell on the remote machine is `tcsh`, but my code requires it to run `bash`. I have tested the sshing some simple commands and it works fine.

```
$ ssh localhost -p 2222 'echo $0'
tcsh
```

To change the login shell I have added to my `.tcshrc` file following two lines:

```
setenv SHELL /bin/bash
exec /bin/bash --login
```

The following thing works:

```
$ ssh localhost -p 2222
[user@remote ~]$ echo $0
/bin/bash
```

But not the following:

```
$ ssh localhost -p 2222 'echo $0'
```

which gives no response. The same for the connections with paramiko established by the code I want to use.

At the moment I am limited only to user-level solutions and would rather not play with the paramiko-using-code itself. Is there anything else I could try here?

Comment: This is a hard - you don't control the `ssh` call, you can't change your default shell properly since you don't have `admin` rights. I don't think you can use `ssh` simply like this with something interactive running within your `rc`. Might be worth exploring addressing this as a design problem - through a talk with the admin to change the default shell for a specific machine, or controlling the `ssh` command.